# why does not CBOW of word2vec include center word in context

Tags: word2vec

In CBOW, each word has input vector and output vector, or context vector and self vector,  the context aggregate the surrounding words, what if the context also contain the input vector of the center word?

Answer (score 1):

Both CBOW and Skipgram models (from the word2vec paper) consider each (*target*) word in turn together with nearby words within a fixed window (*context* words). The CBOW model learns to predict the target from its surrounding context words. Skipgram does the opposite.

Ideally, any word embeddings of *similar* words should have *similar* embeddings. That happens in word2vec embeddings because similar target words have similar distributions of context words around them and so similar parameters (i.e. the embeddings) predict them, e.g. if *dog* appears with *walk*, *tail*, *kennel*, etc and *hound* also appears with those words, then *dog* and *hound* have similar embeddings.

If the target word is included in the distribution of context words (*dog* in the context words of *dog*, *hound* in those of *hound*) they occur in the context distribution *every time* the target word appears, rather then some times like other context words, so have a dominant effect. That creates a *difference* between the two context distributions and so a difference between the embeddings, which probably then perform worse at tasks that require similar words to have similar embeddings.